# Check box checked issue with previously checked/unchecked objects

Tags: jquery, checkbox

[image]

iam working with group of check boxes

**Issue:** iam getting previously unchecked check box objects. iam using jquery to get those checked checkboxs like below

```
 var defaultChecked = $('input[name=default]:checked');
```

**Note:** previous objects are showing thin color (inactive state) in image attached above

***Requirement:*** finally i should able to get only present checked checkboxes objects in my defaultChecked varible.

Comment: okay! what is the question then? i guess you forgot to ask.

Comment: @jai i updated my question please take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can make a reference like `this`:

```
var defaultChecked;
var checkedVals = [];
$('input[name=default]').change(function(){
    if(this.checked) { 
       defaultChecked = $(this); // this will be the latest one checked checkbox.
       checkedVals.push(this.value); // push this when checked
    }
});
```

or you can use `$.map().get()` to get the values as an array:

```
var checkedVals = $.map($('input[name=default]:checked'), function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: if more than one check boxes checked how to get multiple checked values